# Animating smoothly with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I want to achieve the animation effect close to "Current Promotion" section of the site http://www.turningstone.com/. Please scroll down below the home page of the link. It is present just above the footer section. The block is collection of square blocks. On a click on very first block , a "Description of block" will slide out from left and on another click it will revert to previous state.

I have created a demo fiddle to create a replica of the same. Here is the [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rnLjyfnn/). I have added the effect to very first block. However , I am unable to achieve the same. I have used "jQuery" animate property for the same. Though I am able to add animations in very first click , on second click , The animation effect completely disappears , just wondering "How"?

Here is what changes been done , on a click to the block.

1. Toggle a class "is--active" that , ultimately set the "Display" property of "Description" i.e "promo-content" section of the block.
2. Add "Left" value to "promo-content" to slide it from left.

On Another click on the Block , both the above listed property will be removed.

JS Fiddle Demo:

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rnLjyfnn/)

Reference URL:

Current Promotion section of "[turningstone.com](http://turningstone.com)"

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/320/city/" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="promo-content">
            <div class="row">
                 <h4>Hello</h4>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/320/city/" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/320/city/" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-xs-4 {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.promo-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    top: 0;
    background: #ff3e3e;
    z-index: 1;
}
.is--active .promo-content {
    display: block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var width = $(".row .col-xs-4").width(); //Caluclate Width of Each Column
var tw_width = $(".row .col-xs-4").width() * 2; // Width of a column * 2 = Width of Promo Content Box i.e the red box
$('.promo-content').css('width', tw_width); // Assign the width of Promo content box
var left__promoblock = $('.row .col-xs-4:nth-child(3n+1)');
left__promoblock.click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('is--active');
    if ($(this).hasClass("is--active")) {
        $(this).find('.promo-content').animate({
            left: width
        }, 'fast');
    } else {
        $(this).find('.promo-content').animate({
            left: -width
        }, 'fast');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for this?: http://jsfiddle.net/rnLjyfnn/3/

```
left__promoblock.click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass("is--active")) {
        $this.addClass('is--active');
        $this.find('.promo-content').animate({
            left: width
        }, 'fast');
    } else {
        $this.find('.promo-content').animate({
            left: -width
        }, 'fast', function(){
            $this.removeClass('is--active');
        });
    }
});
```

If you look at [the `animate` JQuery API page](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), you will find this:

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

You must remove the class (because of the `display` property) only after the easing is done.

---

This one enables multiple rows: http://jsfiddle.net/danvim/rnLjyfnn/6

Comment: a little help : I have modified the fiddle : Please check here .. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/swapnaranjita_nayak/rnLjyfnn/4/) .. I have added another row .. I want to close the Description block while another one is open...